# parent.postMessage(data) failing

Tags: php, apache

This may be more of an Apache issue, but I am experiencing the issue within php.

I have a php page that is called from within an iframe from a separate HTML page. I return the results from the php utilizing parent.postMessage(data); This had been working without issue. Changes were made in XFRAME options to allow an external site to access the page within the iframe.

"data" is a JSON HTML encoded array.

Now parent.postMessage(data) fails and the browser (Edge) gives the error "0: Argument not optional".

I am not familiar enough with Apache options to point the admin toward what might resolve the issue. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

postMessage expects two arguments, so the second argument (target argument) is not optional, to fix this you would have to write `parent.postMessage(data, '*')`